# how to make custom pin like friends map of 4sq app

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

How to make custom pin like foursquare friends map instead of pin on map?

image is here, http://www.socialmedianews.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/foursquare-friends-map.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation      {
MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];

 if (!pinView) {
    pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"] autorelease];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SPOON4.png"];
    pinView.frame = CGRectMake(-30, 0, 70, 67.5); 
    //pinView.animatesDrop = YES; can't animate with custom pin images
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;


    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

} else {
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
    return nil; //default to blue dot
}
return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> You can use the MKAnnotationView class
>   as is or subclass it to provide custom
>   behavior as needed. The image property
>   of the class lets you set the
>   appearance of the annotation view
>   without subclassing directly. You
>   might also create custom subclasses as
>   a convenience and use them to put the
>   annotation view in a known state. For
>   example, the MKPinAnnotationView
>   subclass initializes the contents of
>   the annotation view to a pin image.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the custom pin with a framed portrait. You can draw the frame with Quartz, or add the frame as a second transparent image. I would do the second adding the following to MKAnnotationView:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
         reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.portraitImage.size.width, self.portraitImage.size.height);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        [self.frameImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.width, frameImage.height)];
        [self.portraitImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, portraitImage.width, portraitImage.height)];
}
```